How to scrape data from webpage using selenium
I would like to scrape all exhibitor names and information from this link: https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/
into a csv file.
I have this written this:
html = requests.get('https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/').text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
exhibitor_links = []
for link in bs.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        exhibitor_links.append(link.attrs['href'])
        print(link.attrs['href'])

exhibitor_names = []
exhibitor_info = []
exhibitor_web = []
exhibitor_linkedin = []
exhibitor_twitter = []
exhibitor_email = []
exhibitor_contact = []
exhibitor_booth = []

base_url = "https://attend.informatechevents.virtual.informatech.com/"
for link in exhibitor_links:
    url = base_url + link
    bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
 
    name = bs.find('h1', class_= "sc-c418aba9-7 dbnofQ").text
    info_div = bs.find('div', class_='sc-dd6f9f7c-0 hIHCKf')

    # Get exhibitor information
    if info_div:
        info_paras= info_div.find_all('p')
        info = '\n'.join([p.get_text() for p in info_paras])
        exhibitor_info.append(info)
    else:
        exhibitor_info.append("")
    exhibitor_names.append(name)

    # Get exhibitor website, contact, email
    tel = ""
    website = ""
    email = ""

    contact_links = bs.find_all('a', class_='sc-2d6f1d18-0 isnIyX')
    for a in contact_links:
        href = a.get('href')
        if href and 'tel:' in href:
            tel = href.split('tel:')[1]
        elif href and 'http' in href:
            website = href
        elif href and 'mailto:' in href:
            email = href.split('mailto:')[1]

    exhibitor_contact.append(tel)
    exhibitor_web.append(website)
    exhibitor_email.append(email)

    # Get exhibitor linkedin and twitter
    linkedin = ""
    twitter = ""

    social_links = bs.find_all('a', {'target': '_blank', 'rel': 'noopener noreferrer'})
    for a in social_links:
        href = a.get('href')
        if href and 'linkedin' in href:
            linkedin = href
        elif href and 'x.com' in href:
            twitter = href

    exhibitor_twitter.append(twitter)
    exhibitor_linkedin.append(linkedin)

    # Get booth number
    booth = ""
    booth_div = bs.find('div', class_='sc-901e7a18-2 eEIcVK')
    if booth_div:
        booth_span = booth_div.find('span', class_='sc-c3d23e77-0 epfMQJ')
        if booth_span:
            booth = booth_span.text
    
    exhibitor_booth.append(booth)

# Create a DataFrame
exhibitors_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Exhibitor Name': exhibitor_names,
    'Event Info' : exhibitor_booth,
    'Description': exhibitor_info,
    'Website': exhibitor_web,
    'Linkedin' : exhibitor_linkedin,
    'Twitter' : exhibitor_twitter,
    'Email' : exhibitor_email,
    'Contact' : exhibitor_contact
})

However, I am only able to get scrape 50 exhibitors despite there being clearly more than 50. I think it is because the page is dynamic which means I might need to use selenium. However, I am not familiar with selenium. Is there a way to integrate it into my existing code?
Thanks in advance.

Selenium will do the job, however I don't think its a good idea to integrate it in your existing code as the two ways are separated. Also selenium is easy so you don't need much experience to automate your task.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here is the selenium solution:
First the algorithm, so that you understand the selenium code:

Launch URL
Switch into the IFRAME, as the targeted elements are inside an IFRAME
Keep scrolling down the page so that the last sponsor name is displayed on the screen
Now that all the sponsor names are visible on the page, scrape it and store it wherever you want(like a variable, csv file etc.)

Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "IframeModule_iframe__JCvXg")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
match=False
while(match==False):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    last_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Singapore Centre for Social Enterprise, raiSE Ltd']")
    if (len(last_element) >= 1):
        match=True

# In the below code I am just printing the names to the console, you can extend code to save it to a variable or into a csv file etc.
names = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sc-a13c392f-0 sc-85df61db-4 feepZZ eErKol']")))
print("length of sponsors and exhibitors= " + str(len(names)))
print("-----Names-----")
for name in names:
    print(name.text)

Console result:
length of sponsors and exhibitors= 857
-----Names-----
AWS
Google
Blackmagic Design Asia Pte Ltd
IBM
INTELSAT
Kacific Broadband Satellites Ltd
ManageEngine
SES World Skies Singapore Pte Ltd
ST ENGINEERING IDIRECT
APT SATELLITE COMPANY LIMITED
Arista Networks
ASIASAT
CANON SINGAPORE PTE LTD
China Satellite Communications Co.,Ltd.
DiTel (ZheJiang) Communication Technology CO., Ltd.
Eutelsat Group
Godox Photo Equipment Co., Ltd.
GRANDSTREAM
H2O.ai
KRATOS
KT SAT CO., LTD.
SKY PERFECT JSAT CORPORATION
TE Connectivity
Thuraya Telecommunications Company
ABV INTERNATIONAL
Appliot
BIRDSAT
Broadcast Communications International Pte Ltd
CPI
Disrupt-X
Docusign
Druid Software
GILAT SATELLITE NETWORKS LTD
IKEGAMI ELECTRONICS ASIA PACIFIC PTE LTD
Intellian Singapore Pte Ltd
IRDETO SINGAPORE PTE LTD
IRIDIUM COMMUNICATIONS INC
Magna Systems & Engineering
Micronet Union Technology (Chengdu) Co., Ltd.
Midwich Asia Pte Ltd
NANGUANG PHOTO & VIDEO SYSTEMS CO LTD
Raisecom Technology Co., Ltd.
RIEDEL COMMUNICATIONS GMBH & CO KG
Shanghai Baud Data Communication Co.,Ltd
SpeQtral X Toshiba
SWIT Electronics Co.,Ltd.
The Northern Alliance
ZIXI
ZTT International Limited
Maritime and Port Authority of Singapore
Symphony Creative Solutions
Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds, P.C.
Krislab, SIA Digital Innovation Lab
Marks & Clerk Singapore LLP
Singapore Science Park Limited
China Sinda Intellectual Property Pte Ltd
Republic Polytechnic
Singapore University of Social Sciences
Temasek Polytechnic
6WIND
A Broadcasting Cinematic Solutions Pte Ltd
ABS
Actelis Networks
Actus Digital
Advantech Wireless Technologies Inc
AEQ SA
AEV Broadcast
Agile Content
AI-Media
AITELONG
Alan Photo Pte Ltd
ALDENA
Alrighty Labs Pte Ltd
Alternative Video Production (AI Photobooth)
Altimedia Corporation
Amazon Web Services
Anhui Xianghe Communication Company
Anhui Yetvo Optoelectronics Technology Co.， Ltd.
APB
APNIC Pty Ltd
APPEAR AS
Apposite Technologies
Aputure
Aqua Broadcast Ltd
Arkona Technologies
Asia Pacific Assistive Robotics Association
Asia Pacific Broadcasting Union (ABU)
Association of Small & Medium Enterprises (ASME)
AST Microwave
Astera GmbH
astTECS GmbH
ATDI SOUTH PACIFIC PTY LTD
ATEME S.A
Atheras Analytics
ATRON CO., LTD
AV8 MEDIA PTE LTD
AVECO
Avid Technology
AvL Technologies
AVLite Pte Ltd
AVSYSTEM
AxelTech
Aximmetry
Ayecka Communication Systems Ltd.
BACKLIGHT
Baicells Technologies Co., Ltd.
BBT ANTENNAS INC.
BDATA Solutions Inc
Beatdapp Software Inc.
BEIJING B.E.D-TECH MANUFACTURE CO., LTD.
Beijing Bridge Image Trading Co., Ltd.
Beijing Bunch Exhibition Services Ltd
Beijing Huahuan Electronics Co., Ltd.
Beijing Jaeger Communication Electronic Technology Co. , Ltd.
Beijing Tianying Vision Technology Co., Ltd.
Beijing United Victory Co., Ltd
Benchmark Broadcast Systems (S) Pte Ltd
BitCyber
BITMOVIN
Blackcam 4D GmbH
BlendVision
Bluefish444
Bridge Technologies
Broadcast Traffic Systems
BROADPEAK
Broadstream Solutions
BTESA - Broad Telecom
bunny.net
C-COM SATELLITE SYSTEMS INC.
C-LIGHT NETWORK COMMUNICATION CO.,LTD.
Calian, Advanced Technologies
Cambium Networks
CANARA LIGHTING IND PVT LTD
Canare Singapore
CARELINK COMMUNICATION LTD
Caton Technology
CDNetworks Singapore Pte Ltd
Ceyear Technologies Co., Ltd
CFOFC COMMUNICATIONS LTD.
CHANGZHOU HUNSEEN INTERNATIONAL TRADING CO.,LTD
Changzhou LINKET Electronic Technology Co. Ltd
Chelsio Communications
Chengdu Bearing New Machinery Equipment Co., LTD
CHENGDU BOLEIN TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.
Chengdu Global-Way Communication Technology Co.,Ltd.
Chengdu Gwatt Technology Co., Ltd.
Chengdu Huajing Communication Equipment Co.,Ltd.
Chengdu Leader Microwave Technology Co.,Ltd
Chengdu Maipu International Infotech Co., Ltd.
Chengdu Shinehigher Technology Co.,Ltd
Chengdu Shuwei Communication Technology Co., Ltd.
Chengdu Sicoresemi Semiconductor Co.,Ltd
Chengdu Skylink Intellitech Co., Ltd.
Chengdu Yuexiang Technology Co., Ltd.
Chengdu Zysen Technology Co., Ltd.
CHINA HUAXIN ANTENNA
China Starwin Science & Technology Co., Ltd
China Telecom (Asia Pacific) Pte Ltd
Chyron
CIG
Cixi YaXun Communication Equipment Co.,Ltd
Clear-Com
COBALT DIGITAL
Cogent (Beijing) Technologies Co., Limited
Colony Networks
COM-TECH ITALIA SPA
COMMPOLAR COMMUNICATION,SHANGHAI,CO,.LTD.
Comtech Telecommunications Corp.
CONTEC
coralbay.tv
Corsight
Cowave Communication Technology Co., Ltd.
CRONUS PRO INDIA PVT LTD
CTC UNION TECHNOLOGIES CO LTD
CUBE EYE (MEERECOMPANY)
Cxrus Solutions Pte Ltd
DAC System SA
DALET
Danyang Teruilai Electronics Co.,Ltd
Datavideo Technologies (S) Pte Ltd
DB Elettronica Telecomunicazioni S.p.A
DCSS Technology Pte Ltd
Deepchecks Ltd
Delta Meccanica s.r.l
DEMARKED INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY SERVICES
Desisti Asia Pte Ltd
DEV Systemtechnik GmbH
Dielectric
DIGIGRAM
Dingshengwei Electronics Co.,Ltd（SOUKA）
Disk Archive Corporation
DRAGON PATH TECHNOLOGIES CO.，LTD
DULENS
DupliCALL Co., Ltd.
EarthDaily Analytics
Earthsight International
EAST PHOTONICS
Easy Media Suite
Easy Media Suite
Eddystone Broadcast Limited
EDITSHARE
EGATEL S.L.
Elecard
Electronics & Engineering Pte Ltd
Elevate Broadcast Pte Ltd
EMAM, Inc
Emtelle UK Ltd
Enensys
EngageLab
Enghouse Systems Limited
EOPTOLINK TECHNOLOGY
ESCENE COMMUNICATION CO., LIMITED
Etere Pte Ltd
ETL SYSTEMS LTD
ETRI
ETRONTIMES TECHNOLOGY PTE LTD
Eutelsat
Event Solutions LLP
EVERTZ MICROSYSTEMS LTD
EVS Broadcast Equipment Limited
EXCELLENCE WIRE INDUSTRIAL CO LTD
EXIR BROADCASTING
FARMERS WIFE SL
Farpoint
Fiber International Technologies Pte Ltd
Fibersen Technology PTE Ltd
FibreSpeare Co., Ltd.
floLIVE
Flyin Group Co., Ltd
Flyingvoice Network Technology Co.， Ltd.
Fobi
FOR-A Company Limited
Friendly Technologies
Fujian Satlink Electronics Co.,Ltd
FUJIFILM Asia Pacific Pte Ltd
GatesAir
GB Labs Limited
GBS Alliance Pte Ltd
General Electronics & Instrumentation Corporation Pte Ltd
GERMANY - FEDERAL MINISTRY FOR ECONOMIC AFFAIRS & CLIMATE ACTION
Gevme
Gigatronix
Glare Productions GmbH
Glensound
GLOBAL INVACOM GROUP LIMTED
Goose
Gospell Digital Technoligy Co., Ltd
Government of Alberta, Canada
Government of British Columbia Canada
Graphen
Grass Valley
Great Britain and Northern Ireland Pavilion
Green Streams GmbH
Guangdong Annderson communication equipment Co., LTD
Guangdong Huajiayu Technology Co.,Ltd
Guangdong Seneasy Intelligent Technology Co., Ltd
Guangdong UNIPOE IOT Technology Co.,Ltd
GUANGZHOU V-SOLUTION TELECOMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.
Guilin G-Link Technology Co., Ltd
HANGZHOU CNCR-IT CO., LTD.
Hangzhou Ctekcom Technology Co., LTD
HANGZHOU DF CABLE CO., LTD.
HANGZHOU PREMLINK TECH CO., LTD
Hangzhou Putianle Cable Co., Ltd.
HANGZHOU REGO ELECTRON CO., LTD.
Hangzhou Risun Cable Co.,Ltd
HANGZHOU ZHIYI COMMUNICATION CO., LTD
HARMONIC INC
Hashstacs Pte Ltd
Hefei Maniron Electronic and Technology Co., Ltd
Helios Technologies
Henan Huachuang Communication Equipment Co.,Ltd.
Hi-Tech Electronics Pte Ltd
HIGH COMMISSION OF CANADA
hiSky
HITACHI KOKUSAI ELECTRIC ASIA (SINGAPORE) PTE. LTD.
HK YONGNUO LIMITED.
HOLLYLAND
Hongan Group Corporation Limited
HORISEN AG
Hunan Gmcine Technology Co., Ltd.
I.O.T. Workz Pte. Ltd.
IABM
IASA Asia Pacific
iBwave Solutions
Ideal Systems (Singapore) Pte Ltd
IECEP
IGSGroup Pte Ltd
IHSE GmbH Asia Pacific Pte Ltd
IIJ Global Solutions Singapore
Illumia Labs
Imagine Communications IC (Singapore) Pte Ltd
IMDA
IMS Mahajak Pro Audio Pte Ltd
Incognito Software Systems
Indonesian Internet Service Providers Association (APJII)
Inetco
Infoesearch
Informa Tech
INFOTECH SOLUTIONS PT
INKA ENTWORKS INC
Inovonics Broadcast
INTEGRASYS S.A
INTERRA SYSTEMS
Intinor AB
Intracom Telecom
Intrinsic Innovations
IP Infusion
Irix Lens
IRT TECHNOLOGIES INC.
IRTE
ISRAEL EXPORT INSTITUTE
iWOW Technology Ltd
J&S Telecoms Int'l Pte Ltd
JAA SYSTEMS SDN. BHD.
Jiangsu Ginlier Communication Technology Co.，Ltd.
JIANGSU HENGXIN TECHNOLOGY CO LTD
Jiangsu Trigiant Technology Co., Ltd.
Jiangsu TX Plastic Optical Fibers Co.,Ltd.
Jiangsu Xuben Photoelectric Technology Co.,ltd
Jiangsu Yatigers Communication Technology Co., Ltd.
Jiangsu Yinhe Electronics Co., Ltd.
JIANGSU YITONG HIGH TECH CO., LTD
Jinan USR IOT Technology Ltd.
JM Broadcast
JONSA TECHNOLOGIES CO LTD
JS Denki Pte Ltd
Jumpstart Disruptive Innovations Pte. Ltd
JWIPC Technology Co.,Ltd.
JWP
JYC Electronic CO.,LTD
KALTURA
KAPID
Kathrein Broadcast GmbH
KENBOTONG COMMUNICATION LTD. FOSHAN
Kingsat Communications Co.,Ltd
KINGTON OPTIC CO.,LTD
Kingtype Technologies Corp.,Ltd.
KODICA
KomShine Technologies Limited
Konvision
KT CORPORATION
Latticeflow AI
Lawo AG
Layercake
LEADER ELECTRONICS CORPORATION
Leaseweb Singapore
Lemo Asia Pte Ltd
Leofoto
LIBEC ASIA PACIFIC PTE LTD
LILLIPUT/AVMATRIX
LIVEU LTD
LongXing
Lootom Telcovideo Network (Wuxi) Co., Ltd.
LS telcom AG
Lynx-Technik Pte Ltd
Macking Domain Pte Ltd
Magna Systems & Engineering (S) Pte Ltd
Magnaquest Technologies
Mantaray USA Corporation
MarkAny
Master D'Imaging Pte Ltd
MASTERCLOCK INC.
MEDIAGENIX ASIA
MEDIAKIND
Mediaware Systems Pte Ltd
Memory Anchor
METRAWEATHER PTY LTD
Minerva Networks Inc.
MING CHIANG PRECISION CO LTD
MINISTRY OF ECONOMIC DEVELOPMENT, JOB CREATION AND TRADE (ONTARIO)
Ministry of Industry Republic of Indonesia
Mission Microwave
ModernTV
MOKO SMART
Moomoo Financial Singapore Pte. Ltd.
MRDcom Co., Ltd.
MSA Focus International Limited
Murano Pte Ltd
MWA Nova GmbH
NANJING DVP OE TECH CO.,LTD
Nanjing Dynacore Technology Co.,Ltd
Nanjing Fiber Artisan Co.,Ltd.
Nanjing Huamai Technology Co.,Ltd.
Nanjing Jilong Optical Communication Co., Ltd.
Nanjing Maxon O.E. Tech. Co., Ltd.
Nanjing Nagasoft Corporation
Nanjing Rapcare Telecommunication Equipment CO.,LTD
NAUTEL
Nautilus SIP Pte Ltd
ND SATCOM GmbH
NEOX NETWORKS GmbH
NETAND
Neterra
Netsweeper Inc.
Network Innovations Inc.
Nevion
New Cine Pte Ltd
NEXCOM INTERNATIONAL CO LTD
NEXGENWAVE CO LTD
Nexologies Limited
NextZen Minds
NIHON DENGYO KOSAKU Co., Ltd.
NINGBO GEYIDA CABLE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
NINGBO GMF TELECOM TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
NINGBO OCEAN COMMUNICATIONS EQUIPMENT LIMITED
NINGBO TIANLI COMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.
Nisshinbo Micro Devices Inc.
Norsat International Inc.
Novella SatComs Ltd
NOVELSAT Ltd.
NTT TechnoCross Corporation
NUIVA
NUS Enterprise
NXCLOUD
ODOO HK
Ofisgate & QA Cafe.
OMB BROADCAST
Omdia
Open Broadcast Systems
OpenRep AI
ORBAN EUROPE GMBH
Orbcomm
Orbital Research
Ortana Media Group
OTRS ASIA
P1 Security
Pacific Islands Telecommunications Association
Pals Elektronik
Panther GmbH
PEAK COMMUNICATIONS LTD
Pebble
PERCON EXPORT SLU
Pipe Lighting GmbH
Pixel Tree
PLANETCAST MEDIA SERVICES LTD
PlayBox NEO (APAC) Pte Ltd
PLISCH GmbH
Plumettaz Singapore Pte Ltd
PolarSat Inc
Polytron Vertrieb GmbH
Potel Cable Group Co.,Ltd.
Powerange (Shenyang) Co., Ltd.
PRIME ELECTRONICS AND SATELLITICS INCORPORATION
PRISM TELECOM
PROGIRA Radio Communication AB
Promateus
PROMAX TEST & MEASUREMENT, SLU.
Providius
Pyras Technology Inc.
Qitian Communication Industry Ningxia Co., Ltd.
Quantum South Asia
Québec
Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd.
Quikbot Technologies
RAD Data Communications Ltd
Radio Frequency Systems GmbH
Radix
Raisecom
Rapidtek Technologies Inc.
REAKO TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD
ReportNOW Asia Pacific Pte Ltd
Research Concepts Inc
REVGO (GUANGZHOU) TELECOM TECHNOLOGY LTD
REZEMON PTE LTD
RFE BROADCAST
Riseup Labs
Rivada Space Networks
ROMANIA IT
Romania Pavilion
Roots Innovation Pte Limited
ROSS VIDEO (SINGAPORE) PTE LTD
RT Software
Rugao KaiKai Telecom Materials Co.,Ltd
SAF Tehnika / Aranet
SAFEblu Fire & Safety
Saranyu Technologies Pvt Ltd
Sat-Lite Technologies
SATCUBE AB
SDMC Technology Co., Ltd
Securicom Solutions
SENER TAFS S.A.U
SENNHEISER ELECTRONIC ASIA PTE LTD
Seoul Business Agency
SGTECH
Shaanxi Academy of Aerospace Technology Application Co., Ltd
Shaanxi Newstar Communications Equipment Co., Ltd
SHANDONG HUAXIN COMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
Shanghai BAOSH Communication Equipment Co., Ltd.
Shanghai Joinwit Optoelectronic Tech.Co.,LTD
Shen Zhen Fibertop Technology Co.,Ltd
Shenzhen Accsoon Technology Co., Ltd
Shenzhen C-Data Technology Co., Ltd.
Shenzhen Comnect Technology Co., Ltd
Shenzhen Crystal Video Technology Co., Ltd.
Shenzhen Depend Electronics Limited
Shenzhen Dongzheng Optical Technology Co., Ltd.
Shenzhen GIEC Digital Co.,Ltd
Shenzhen Gigalight Technology Co.,Ltd.
Shenzhen Golden Star Technology LTD.
Shenzhen Link-all Technology Co., Ltd
SHENZHEN LONTE TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD
Shenzhen Megmeet Electrical Co.,Ltd.
Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co.,Ltd.
Shenzhen Realsea Optoelectronic Technology Co., Ltd.
SHENZHEN SDG INFORMATION CO.,LTD.
Shenzhen SEI Robotics.,Ltd
Shenzhen Shengrun Technology Co.,Ltd
Shenzhen Sopto Technology Co., LTD
Shenzhen Tilta Technology Co.,Ltd
Shenzhen Topband Co., Ltd
SHENZHEN TORCH TELECOM TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD
Shenzhen Walsun Technology Co.,ltd
Shenzhen Wolck Network Product Co.,Ltd.
ShinewayTech International, Inc.
SHOTOKU BROADCAST SYSTEMS
Shotoku Broadcast Systems
SHURE
Sichuan Changhong Neonet Technologies Co.,Ltd
SICHUAN SATEC CO.,LTD
sichuan yuantong communication co.,ltd
Sihong Weichuang Optics CO.,Ltd
Sinclair Technologies
Singapore Institute of Technology
Sino-Telecom Technology Co., Inc
SipRadius LLC
SIRA Radio Systems Srl
SKYCOM Communications Ltd
Skyline Communications
SmallRig
Smart Walkie
SonicFi Inc
SOTI Inc.
Space Star Technology Co., Ltd
SpaceBridge Inc.
Speedcast
Splashtop Singapore Pte Ltd
Squirro Asia Pte. Ltd.
SSL Asia (Sales) Pte Ltd
STAGETEC ASIA
Star Solutions
Stellant Systems
Storj
Stream Labs
Studio Network Solutions (SNS)
Sumavision Technologies Co.,Ltd
SUMEC Machinery & Electric Co., Ltd.
SUNCA CO LTD
Sunwave Communications Co., Ltd
SUNWODA ENERGY TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD
Suzhou Alton Electronics Technology Co.,Ltd.
SUZHOU GREEN TELECOM TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD
SUZHOU NOARK TELECOM CO., LTD.
Suzhou Spideradio Telecommunication Technology Co., Ltd
SYES
SYNAMEDIA
Synology Inc.
T3 INDUSTRIAL CO LTD
TAG Video Systems
TAIWAN ELECTRICAL AND ELECTRONIC MANUFACTURERS' ASSOCIATION
TAKFLY GROUP
Tarana Wireless Inc
TATUNG COMPANY
TEEMA
Teknobuilt
TEKTELIC Communications Inc
Telecom Equipment & Services Export Promotion Council (TEPC)
Telecom Review Asia
Teledyne Paradise Datacom
Telesat
TELESTREAM LLC
TELIKOU Technologies Co., Ltd
TELRAD NETWORKS LTD
Telstra Broadcast Services
TEMIX Communications
Tempo Communications Inc.
Terrasat Communications Inc.
Thaicom Public Company Limited
The French Chamber of Commerce in Singapore
The Media Village Pte Ltd
The WIll-Burt Company
TIANJIN DEVISER ELECTRONICS INSTRUMENT CO LTD
Tianjin Eloik Communication Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.
TIANYI SATCOM CO., LTD
Tozed Kangwei Tech Co., Ltd
Tozed Kangwei Tech Co., Ltd
Transcom(Nanjing) Information Technology Co., Ltd
TREDESS 2010, S.L
TSC Trakking
TSL Products
TULIX
Turnium Network Solutions Inc.
U.S. Department of Commerce
Ubiqconn Technology, Inc
UNABIZ PTE LTD.
Unionman Technology Co.,Ltd
UniqCast
Univiso Technologies and Develop Limited
Uptempo Global
Uptempo Global
Userful Corporation
V-Nova
Vantron Technology Inc
Varnish Software Pte Ltd
Version 2 Singapore
VIACCESS-ORCA
ViaLite Communications
Videndum Production Solutions Limited
VIDEOCRYPT
Vidtech Pte Ltd
Viet Nam National Pavilion
VIKING SATCOM
Village Island Co., Ltd.
Vislink
VITEC
VoiceInteraction – Tecnologias de Processamento da Fala, SA
VS ONE WORLD (PTE.) LTD
WASABI
Wellav Technologies Ltd.
Wellbe System Indonesia
Whiteways Systems Pte Ltd
Win-Asia Software
Wirlink Creative Solution Limited Company
WITBE
WOHLER TECHNOLOGIES
WonderNet LTD.
WORK Microwave GmbH
WORKFLOWLABS (ASIA) SDN. BHD.
WorldCast Systems
WUHAN ESION OPTIC INC.LTD
Wuhan Yangtze Optical Technologies Co., Ltd.
Wuxi Taclink Optoelectronics Technology Co., Ltd.
WYPLAY
X10 Technologies
Xena Vision Corp.
Xiamen Alotcer Communication Technology
XipLink Inc
XMW INC
Xtaltq Technologies Co., Limited
YoloLiv Technology
Yonyou
Yukuan Technology Ltd
Yuyao Jera Line Co., Ltd.
Yuyao Lishuai Film & Television
YUZZIT
ZCorum
Zenithtel Inc.
Zenon-Media GmbH
Zhangzhou Seetec Optoelectronics Technology Co.,Ltd
ZHEJIANG CHAOQIAN TELECOMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.
ZHEJIANG DUMEI COMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD
ZHEJIANG GUANGDA PUTE COMMUNICATION TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
Zhejiang Hongyou Optic Tech Co.,Ltd
ZHEJIANG JIXIANG CABLE MANUFACTURING CO.,LTD
ZHEJIANG TIANJIE INDUSTRIAL CORP.
ZHEJIANG TRIBRER COMMUNICATION LIMITED
ZHEJIANG WANMA TIANYI COMMUNICATION WIRE & CABLE CO., LTD.
ZHEJIANG ZHAOLONG INTERCONNECT TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.
Zhejiang Zhengdao Technologies Co., Ltd
Zhongruisulian(Wuhan) Technology CO LTD
Zhuhai Gotech Intelligent Technology Co., Ltd.
ZHUHAI HANSEN TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD
ZINWELL CORPORATION
ZTE Corporation
Zycoo Co.,Ltd
ENITT Co., Ltd.
FOSTEC INC
IOLITE
Korea Optron Corp.
MS TECH CO., LTD
SOLTECH Co., Ltd.
SUNIL Telecom Co.,LTD
Tronix
A.J. WORLD CO., LTD.
Fin Insight Co., Ltd
KICTA
mcloudoc
NES Co., Ltd.
NEXTLab Co., LTD
PPI INC.
RF MORECOM COREA CO.,LTD
Testonic Co., Ltd
tlooto
VISSEM Electronics Co., Ltd.
Y.TECH Co., Ltd.
ANYRACTIVE CO.,LTD.
AUTOL
AUTONOMOUS A2Z CO., LTD.
INFINIQ
INSUNG METAL CO., LTD
KOTRA/KICTA
LABLUP INC.
MOBILINT
MOVEMENTS INC.
REPOWERTEK INC.
THE CODER CO., LTD.
TICON SYSTEM CO., LTD.
WATA INC.
ZCONVERTERCLOUD INC.
CASTIS Co. LTD.
intween
IT Servant
LaON Technology Co., Ltd.
NEOVISION
Visual Research Inc.
Way Audio Co., Ltd.
MARUSYS
Mathpresso, Inc.
N-iTUS.CO.,LTD.
O2O Inc.
Onecup
SungChang Co.,Ltd.
Wooriro Co., Ltd.
3Y Energy
A Company Co., Lte
Accelerice
Acoerela
Active Silvers
Addlly AI Pte Ltd
Ailytics Pte Ltd
AIOT
AirCity
Aires Applied Technology
Akesis Biologics
Algobio
Anytime Work
Ara Research
Ark Zhou: Study Abroad, together!
Armastec
AsageAI
Ateneo De Manila University
AuroraFood Pte Ltd
AxisNow
Biometallica
BroilerX
Campus Film
Carbonwize Co., Ltd
China Sinda Intellectual Property Pte Ltd
ConcreteAI
ConnectingDNA Global Pte. Ltd.
CRecTech
CyberSG TIG Collaboration Centre
Datality Lab
DeepSignature
Digital Life Line
Eigensensor
Enfarm Agritech
Factorem
FathomX Pte Ltd
Ferticlay
Fingerdance
Foodmap Asia
Forte Biotech Pte Ltd
Fronka Tech Pte Ltd
Graffity
Green COP Pte Ltd
Haobotics Medical Technology (Suzhou) Co.,Ltd.
HealthBridge AI
Herb Guardian
Hydgen
ifufan
Ijo
ImmunTech Singapore Pte Ltd
Inside Technologies
Institut Pertanian Bogor (IPB)
Institut Pertanian Bogor (IPB)
Invigilo
ITB LPIK
ITB LPIT
Jaz
Jubelo
Kleensoil Environmental Technologies Pte Ltd
KOMINFO Indonesia
KOMINFO Indonesia
Kosmode Health Singapore Pte Ltd
Lactation Buddys
Ledgerowl
Lembaga Pengelola Dana Pendidikan (LPDP) Karla Bionics/Cube Studio
Lembaga Pengelola Dana Pendidikan (LPDP) LightenUp/Nexmedis
Librarian Pte. Ltd.
Lingosnap
M.I. Cloud
MADCash
MAGES Studio
Malloy Labs
MangaChat
Marina Chain
MeasureAI
MetaDAP
Microtube Technologies Pte. Ltd.
Mindful Beverages
Miraico Technologies
Modelbest
Multi-Field Precision
mVizn Pte. Ltd.
Nanolumi
Nanomatics
Nautilus Labs
New Taipei City Government Youth Department
NextBlock
Nusmetics Pte Ltd
NuSpace Pte Ltd
Paperlux
Pawsible Food
Pebblely Pte Ltd
PIER71
Power Facade
Probicient
Project Enigma
ProSpace Pte Ltd
Quantified Energy Labs
Raijin AI Pte Ltd
raiSE
Ravenry
Rebit Labs Pte. Ltd.
Red Dot Drone
RIDM
RoPlus Pte Ltd
Scholarly
School of Computer Science and Engineering, Nanyang Technological University
School on Cloud
Seamless XR
Shenzhen Ruyichuangjing Education Technology Co., Ltd.
Shoe Agtech Jsc
Singapore Blockchain Innovation Program
Skilio
SMARTR.CO
Smartsense
Somin Pte Ltd
Soynergy
SpaceMatch Pte Ltd
StratifiCare
Suntar Research
Synesthesias, Inc
Tech Up Advance Pte Ltd
TechnoGIS
The Moonbeam.co
tHEMEat
Thiospark
Tigtag.io
Trakomatic Pte Ltd
Treatsure
Unilah Sdn Bhd
Universitas Gadjah Mada (UGM)
Universitas Gadjah Mada (UGM)
Universitas Indonesia (UI)
Universitas Indonesia (UI)
Universitas Tarumanagara (UNTAR)
Universiti Brunei Darussalam
UNPAD
Vibefam
Vilota Pte Ltd
Whyre Technologoies
Xellar
Zhipu.AI
Femtech
Singapore Centre for Social Enterprise, raiSE Ltd

Process finished with exit code 0


How do I get the other information like description and contact details? Doing so requires me to click in
